# SCSS/CSS doesn't load with webpack

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, webpack, sass

I must update legacy code of a Rails app but i don't know why the Front is not display correctly and page loading is very slow,
I can't contact the past developers

[image]

[image: production]

I got the code from heroku and it works well in production but not in development environment

When i launched the app for the first time i had this error

> Webpacker::Manifest::MissingEntryError

And i fix it with

```
yarn install
```

I never used webpacker before in my Rails projects, i tried many things to fix it but it doesnt work and i don't know what is the way to lauch a Rails app correctly

UPDATE

I re installed webpacker on my environment and now the server compile with webpack but i got error about a JS library

```
ERROR in ./app/javascript/packs/landing.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
Error: Cannot find module 'babel-preset-env' from (repository path)
```

Comment: See if this page helps -- https://github.com/rails/webpacker/issues/1523

Comment: Thanks I did the yarn install command and i fixed it but i still have front problems

Comment: Have a look at this then - it outlines a counter-intuitive approach of putting your font directory inside your stylesheets directory. Scoll down for a non-SASS approach (if needed). -- https://gist.github.com/anotheruiguy/7379570

Comment: Wait.. you have FRONT, or FONT, problems?

Comment: Front problems, all cards, background and posititons are not display in develoment env, i update a screen of what it look like in production

Comment: Hmmm. I'm no expert at rails myself, so I'm largely relying on my research skills here. I'm having a lot of trouble finding devleopment env specific problems like this. There's a lot of necessary configuration that I am not familiar with (either on your end, or in general).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't comment yet so I have to create an answer to help you. Your CSS doesn't seem to be compiled in development environment or the CSS files are not imported somehow.

There can be several issues for that.  Do you have any errors in your terminal ? Is your `webpack.yml` well configured for development ?

```
development:
  <<: *default
  compile: true
```

Comment: No i didnt see errors in my rails server logs or in my console

Comment: I updated my ask with the content of my webpack.yml

Comment: Try setting `dev_server:` `host:` to `host: localhost` instead of `host:webpacker`

Comment: Nothing change, i got error when i launch webpacker it can from this ?